# Excel execute SQL Server stored procedure with a parameter

Tags: sql-server, excel

Can anyone help me with the syntax for adding a parameter to a stored procedure for Excel 2016?  In previous versions of Excel the syntax was:

```
{ call dbo.StoredProcName (?) }
```

But this no longer works for Excel 2016.

Comment: Dealing with procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is for SQL server

Comment: That's the correct syntax for ODBC calls. Possibly your call isn't going through ODBC but through the native driver. Try just `dbo.StoredProcName ?` or `dbo.StoredProcName @param=?` or even `dbo.StoredProcName @param`.

Comment: I had tried all of those to no avail..  I have also tried this through the native driver and through ODBC.  Each iteration throws a syntax error.

Comment: That syntax still works for 2016 with SS. I use  {CALL myDatabaseName.dbo.myStoredProc (?)}